# Spring XML + properties configuration to Java Class

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration-files, properties-file

I have the following configuration piece on my xml file:

```
<util:properties id="apiConfigurator" location="classpath:api.properties" scope="singleton"/>
```

And here is my properties file:

```
appKey=abc
appSecret=def
```

On my spring classes I get some of the values like this:

```
@Value("#{apiConfigurator['appKey']}")
```

I would like to create a `@Configuration` class in Spring to parse the properties file in a way that

```
@Value("#{apiConfigurator['appKey']}")
```

still works thorough my classes that use this. How do I properly do that?

Comment: Try [this](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/spring-3-javaconfig-loading-properties.html).

Comment: It looks close but it doesnt say anything about giving the configuration set an id, and making it accessible as the'hash-like' way I need: apiConfigurator['foo']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify

```
<util:properties .../>
```

Spring registers a `PropertiesFactoryBean` bean with the name/id that you also specified.

All you need to do is to provide such a  `@Bean` yourself

```
// it's singleton by default
@Bean(name = "apiConfigurator") // this is the bean id
public PropertiesFactoryBean factoryBean() {
    PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("api.properties"));
    return bean;
}
```